# How to implement page switch by scroll gesture which is already implemented in iOS7?

Tags: ios, animation, gesture

It's nice that back to previous page is so easy by swipe gesture in iOS7, Apple has implemented for you already. We like this feature, but how to implement it on iOS6? Any resource can take reference? Such as open source or design solution.

Please share and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably be inclined to use `UIPageViewController` (which is a nice control that offers swiping between view controllers). If you really want to reproduce the `UINavigationController` iOS 7 UI (swiping from edges rather than anywhere on the page, all of the navigation bar UX, etc.), it might take a little work. But if all you need is a nice simple swiping between view controllers, `UIPageViewController` might be a good place to start.

See the [Page View Controllers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/PageViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011313-CH4-SW3) section of the *View Controller Catalog for iOS.*

Comment: I would also add that you can create a custom solution (if PageViewController doesn't fit to your need) using `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`and its `locationOfTouch:inView:` in order to get the same " swipe from the border of the screen " effect. [More informations here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISwipeGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. UIPageViewController may be a possible solution, but I don't want to do too much code change. If a customize UI control which can achieve it then it will be good idea. Does Apple open source the solution? Thanks.

Comment: @jianhua No, Apple doesn't provide any gesture-based rendition of `UINavigationController` for iOS versions prior to 7. You'd have to look for third-party libraries to do that, but (a) I don't happen to know of any; and (b) I'd be surprised if even they didn't require some non-inconsequential amount of refactoring of your code and UI. But, like I said, I'd be inclined to bite the bullet and move to page view controller and replicate/simulate the navigation bar UX.

Comment: Great, you are right. I will do some experiments based on UIPageViewController.